# Amazon Cognito sync how to register the user for developer authenticated identities?

Tags: amazon-cognito

> I am new to amazon cognito sync, my requirement is to sync the user's data across the devices for this i need to implement the Developer Authenticated identities i have used AmazonCognitoUsersPools Demo to signup and sign the users in UserPools.In federated identites i have created a Identity pool and added my user pool id and app id  while creation.From the AWSCognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationSample guide i have created a stack and generated Application URL. So now i could able to register the users from browser and syncing their data across devices by using the CognitoSyncDemo, is there any way to register the users from mobile app??
>
> My Req is to authenticate and sync the users whoom i have registered through CognitoUserPoolsDemo and Sync their data..When i tried these users in cognito sync its not working, Please any one help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Users registered in Cognito User Pools are not available in Cognito Sync. You can use [Cognito Federated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) to get an identityId for the user, then sync data for this identityId.